# Encoding of categorical variables (dummy vs. effects coding) in mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, categorical-encoding

The model based on the experiment looks like this:

```
glmer(Y ~ X*Condition + (X*Condition|subject) + (1+X|Trial))

# Y = logit variable  
# X = continuous variable  
# Condition = values A and B, dummy coded; the design is repeated 
#             so all participants go through both Conditions  
# subject = random effects for different subjects  
# trial = random effects for different trials
```

Until now, I thought that the interpretation of the interaction and random effects is quite straightforward:

- for fixed effects:

  - Intercept - what is the Y value in Condition 0 when X is 0
  - X - how much does Y change for a change of 1 unit in X in Condition 0
  - ConditionB - what is the difference in Intercept for Condition B from Condition A
  - X*ConditionB - what is the difference in slope for ConditionB from ConditionA
- for random effects:

  - random intercept - random variability around Intercept
  - random X - random variability around X
  - random ConditionB - random variability of the difference of intercepts between ConditionB and ConditionA
  - random X*ConditionB - random variability of difference in slopes between ConditionB and ConditionA

However, I've read through a very well written chapter [*An Introduction to Mixed Models for Experimental Psychology* by **Henrik Singmann** and **David Kellen**](http://singmann.org/download/publications/singmann_kellen-introduction-mixed-models.pdf), where they say

> In other words, a mixed model (or any other regression type model) that includes interactions with factors using treatment contrasts produces parameter estimates as well as Type III tests that often *do not correspond* to what one wants (e.g., main effects are not what is commonly understood as a main effect).

Using effects coding is suggested as a better way to interpret the interactions of continuous variable `X` and categorical variable `Condition`. I am aware that the random effects correlation in the upper case is somewhat hard to interpret - the correlation of Intercept and X is straightforward, but the correlation of X and X:ConditionB is not, because we correlate coefficients with differences from these coefficients. Then one needs to calculate the correlation per hand, as described in [How to compute correlation of random slopes for X between two Conditions with (X*Condition|subject) model in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322376/how-to-compute-correlation-of-random-slopes-for-x-between-two-conditions-with-x)

My questions are:

1. Is my interpretation of fixed and random effects valid? If not, why?
2. Why is effects coding better than dummy coding in mixed models, and how do you interpret effect coding?

Comment: I think the Chapter explains it quite well and a longer quote would provide an answer to your question. (Note that this Q has *nothing* to do with mixed models.) Perhaps you are confused by them mentioning "simple effects" and "main effects". See here http://glimo.vub.ac.be/downloads/simpleeffect.htm or here http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/maplelab/slides/Simple_Main_Effects_Fraundorf.pdf (found by googling; you can easily find more). Your `X` coef is a **simple** effect because it's at Cond=0. A **main** effect would be an effect of X "on average" (across all conditions). But your interp. is fine.

Comment: This is a very good explanation of simple and main effects, very clear and helpful. However, I was aiming at checking whether my interpretation of random effects is correct, which seems so. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As said by @amoeba in the comment, the question is not so much a mixed model question, but more a general question on how to parameterize a regression model with interactions. The full quote from our chapter also provides an answer to your second question (i.e., the why):

> A common contrast scheme, which is the default in R, is called
>   treatment contrasts (i.e., `contr.treatment`; also called dummy
>   coding). With treatment contrasts the first factor level serves as the
>   baseline whereas all other levels are mapped onto exactly one of the
>   contrast variables with a value of 1. As a consequence, the intercept
>   corresponds to the mean of the baseline group and not the grand mean.
>   When fitting models without interactions, this type of contrast has
>   the advantage that the estimates (i.e., the parameters corresponding
>   to the contrast variables) indicate whether there is a difference
>   between the corresponding factor level and the baseline. However, when
>   including interactions, treatment contrasts lead to results that are
>   often difficult to interpret. Whereas the highest-order interaction is
>   unaffected, the lower-order effects (such as main effects) are
>   estimated at the level of the baseline, ultimately yielding what are
>   known as simple effects rather than the usually expected lower-order
>   effects. Importantly, this applies to both the resulting parameter
>   estimates of the lower order effects as well as their Type III tests.
>   In other words, a mixed model (or any other regression type model)
>   that includes interactions with factors using treatment contrasts
>   produces parameter estimates as well as Type III tests that often do
>   not correspond to what one wants (e.g., main effects are not what is
>   commonly understood as a main effect). Therefore we generally
>   recommend to avoid treatment contrasts for models that include
>   interactions.

Orthogonal sum-to-zero contrasts are better because they avoid potentially difficult to interpret lower-order effects. That is, for those contrasts all lower order effects are evaluated at the grand mean. For a quick explanation of dummy vs. effect coding difference, please see: http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/maplelab/slides/Simple_Main_Effects_Fraundorf.pdf

This means for your case, almost all your interpretations are correct with one exception.

- ConditionB - what is the difference in Intercept for Condition B from Condition A, **when X is zero**.

Hence, if zero is somewhat meaningless for your variable (e.g., it is age and you only observe adult participants) your estimate of Condition (which is now a simple effect of condition at X = 0) becomes meaningless as well.

In general, having interactions with continuous covariates is not trivial and there are at least two books and several papers which extensively discuss this issue. A common solution is centering the covariate on the mean. Whether or not this makes sense depends on your covariate. What I sometimes do when having a variable with a restricted range (e.g., it goes from 0 to 100) is to center on the midpoint of the scale (see e.g., [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010028516302870)).

More information on centering can be found in the following references. I recommend you read the first one at least:

- Dalal, D. K., & Zickar, M. J. (2012). Some Common Myths About Centering Predictor Variables in Moderated Multiple Regression and Polynomial Regression. Organizational Research Methods, 15(3), 339-362. [doi:10.1177/1094428111430540](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428111430540) [[free pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael_Zickar2/publication/276949840_Some_Common_Myths_About_Centering_Predictor_Variables_in_Moderated_Multiple_Regression_and_Polynomial_Regression/links/5627b10508aed9017d460e3d/Some-Common-Myths-About-Centering-Predictor-Variables-in-Moderated-Multiple-Regression-and-Polynomial-Regression.pdf)]
- Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S. G., & Aiken, L. S. (2002). [Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805822232). New York: Routledge Academic. [great book]
- Aiken, L. S., & West, S. G. (1991). Multiple regression: testing and interpreting interactions. Newbury Park, Calif.: Sage Publications.

There is also some mixed-model specific discussion on centering, but to me this appears to be mainly relevant for hierarchical structures (i.e., at least two-levels of nesting), e.g.,

- Wang, L., & Maxwell, S. E. (2015). On disaggregating between-person and within-person effects with longitudinal data using multilevel models. Psychological Methods, 20(1), 63–83. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000030

Potentially also relevant:

- Iacobucci, D., Schneider, M. J., Popovich, D. L., & Bakamitsos, G. A. (2016). Mean centering helps alleviate “micro” but not “macro” multicollinearity. Behavior Research Methods, 48(4), 1308–1317. https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-015-0624-x

Comment: +1, great to see you answer this so quickly. Excellent point about whether X=0 is a meaningful baseline. In fact, thinking about what is a *meaningful baseline* is IMHO the right way to approach contrasts. Sometimes it can be the grand mean, sometimes it can be a particular level (or a particular value in case of continuous predictor), and so there isn't one choice of contrasts that is always "most interpretable"...

Comment: By the way, I feel that this part of your Chapter assumes that the reader knows what "main effect" and "simple effect" are. I did not know (or rather, was not quite sure) so googled it, and after seeing the definitions, your text became very clear. Perhaps a footnote or a sentence defining them more explicitly could be helpful.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks. That is a good point. I will add it if we get the chance to revise. And I was only so quick because the OP first asked me via mail and then I asked him to post the question here. Seems more efficient then answering by mail and for his eyes only.

Comment: Henrik, thank you for such a detailed explanation, and clearance. I would suggest you also edit your answer to include the presentation which was added by @amoeba (http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/maplelab/slides/Simple_Main_Effects_Fraundorf.pdf) because it offers a very simple and quick explanation of dummy and effects coding!

Comment: Could you also explain what is the difference between lower-order and higher-order effects?

Comment: @RockyRaccoon A higher-order effect is one involving more than one covariate (i.e., interactions), lower-order effects are those that are subordinate to other higher-order effects (e.g., main effects when an interaction is present or the two-way interactions when a three-way interation is present).